# Eclipse console vs Netbeans Console

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, ide, non-ascii-characters

I  have a file with some non-ASCII character like

```
set myval;[2K[DESC[DESC[D
```

and I have a Java code to read the file

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {

        String sCurrentLine;

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("output.txt"));

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null) {
                br.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

In Netbeans those non ASCII are not shown but in Eclipse console those character are displayed as it is.
I want to know how Netbeans were able to remove those character as i need to clean up my files for those non ASCII characters.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to read the file as bytes, and then configure a specific [`CharsetDecoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html) to remove the bytes you do not want to capture.